# Taking Gazebo screenshots using a ROS node

Tags: ros, gazebo, shell

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Gazebo to make some experiments. I want to take photos of Gazebo simulation in certain moments (decided by my ROS node). Gazebo has a screen capture utility by itself, it can be activated using a GUI button. However, there doesn't seem to be a ROS message or service to trigger it from a ROS node. Am I missing something?

Otherwise, can you suggest me the most modular way to take screenshots of whole screen? Can I create a shell script and rosrun it like a node when necessary? Or should I call screenshot application directly from my ROS node using C++?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255519/taking-gazebo-screenshots-using-a-ros-node/) by [hansolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29473/hansolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2017-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As there is no answer, I am sharing how I solved it back then.

I decided to create a shell script to handle the screenshots. During the execution, ROS node (C++ program) calls the shell file with a system call:

```
string path_str = ros::package::getPath("package_name");
string cmd_str = path_str+"/src/capture_screenshot.sh";

// add path and name arguments
cmd_str += " -p " + path_str + "/output";
cmd_str += " -n " + name_str;

// call the script program
system(cmd_str.c_str());
```

Shell script parses the arguments to create output file's path and captures Gazebo's screen:

```
# read arguments etc...

mkdir -p ${OUTPUT_PATH}

# take the screenshot
import -window Gazebo "${OUTPUT_PATH}/${OUTPUT_NAME}.jpg"
```

You can use additional arguments to tell script to create a new folder or not. Hope it will be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [hansolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29473/hansolo/) with karma: 78 on 2018-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-12**:
Nice of you to report back how you solved this.

It would probably be good to mention that `import` is one of the ImageMagick utilities, and that on Ubuntu it's distributed in the `imagemagick` package.